# How to get the id dynamically to store cookies

Tags: cookies

[image]

Right now I'm getting the id statically in my output "1778a1778"  because of array_push(), but I have to send ID dynamically and get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ID of the current post outside of the loop, you can use `get_queried_object_id()`. Just make sure to check `is_singular()` first, or you could end up storing IDs of things other than posts. This could cause problems if there's overlap with post IDs. I'd share the amended code with those changes, but for some reason you posted a screenshot instead of code, and I'm not writing it out by hand.

Comment: `add_action( 'wp', 'cookies_for_posts' );
function cookies_for_posts() {

    $viewed = array();

    $viewed= get_the_ID();
    $post_arr=array();
    array_push($post_arr,$viewed);
    array_push($post_arr,$viewed);
    $post_str=implode( 'a' , $post_arr);
    
    var_dump($post_str);
    setcookie(
       'cookies_for_posts',
        $post_str,
        time() + 31536000,
        COOKIEPATH,
        COOKIE_DOMAIN,
        false,
        true,
    );
}`

Comment: You can use this and you can suggest me.

Comment: as I have written "  array_push($post_arr,$viewed);  " twice so I'm getting the output after var_dump "  1778a1778  " but what I need is that on page refresh the ID should dynamically get add. 
For ex. 1st-time refresh page.  Output = " 1778 "
2nd-time when I refresh the page.  The output should be = " 1178a1178 "
3rd-time when I refresh. The output should be = " 1778a1778a1778 "
like that

Comment: Your question was about the ID, which I've answered. If you have a new question, then post a new question. Or you should clarify your original question, which at the moment doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm having a douth in the same question so. Thanks Btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp', 'Store_cookies_of_user' );
function Store_cookies_of_user() {  
$ids = isset( $_COOKIE['bsf_docs_cookies'] ) ? explode('a', $_COOKIE['bsf_docs_cookies']) : array();
if( ! in_array(get_the_ID(), $ids) ) {

        // Add to array.
        $ids[] = get_the_ID();

        // Impload with `a` stirng!
        $ids = implode('a', $ids);

        // Increase currend doc view count with 1.
        $count = (int) get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'views', true );
        update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'views', ($count+1) );

        // Set updated ids list.
        setcookie(
           'bsf_docs_cookies',
            $ids,
            time() + 86400,
            COOKIEPATH,
            COOKIE_DOMAIN,
            false,
            true,
        );
    }
}
```